# Hard time understanding the concept of return and multiple returns in python

Tags: python

```
def calc_circle_area(circle_diameter):
    pi_val = 3.14159265

    circle_radius = circle_diameter / 2.0

    circle_area = pi_val * circle_radius * circle_radius

    return circle_area

def pizza_calories(pizza_diameter):

    calories_per_square_inch = 16.7   

    total_calories = calc_circle_area(pizza_diameter) * calories_per_square_inch

    return total_calories

print('12 inch pizza has %.2f calories.'% pizza_calories(12.0))

print('14 inch pizza has %.2f calories.'% pizza_calories(14.0))
```

So with this, I am confused of how the order of "returning" works ...
help? :(

Comment: They return in the order that they are called. It's not clear to me what is confusing you

Comment: Your print statement uses the return value from `pizza_calories(foo)`, which uses the return value from `calc_circle_area(bar)`, in calculating the `total_calories` variable.

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: So once total_calories needs to find what the cal_circle_area(pizza_diameter) is it will go back to the first def, right? from there on it will start its thing until it reaches to return circle_area. I am confused of what return circle_area does that makes it to jump back to return total_calories.. sorry if this is more confusing :( I'm just so lost lol

Answer (score 2):

There is no "order" to returning in the sense I believe you may be thinking of. Each function is a separate piece of code, to which I think your notion of "order" does not apply. For example, if you run a Python script simply containing:

```
def calc_circle_area(circle_diameter):
    pi_val = 3.14159265
    circle_radius = circle_diameter / 2.0
    circle_area = pi_val * circle_radius * circle_radius
    return circle_area
```

The Python script will make a function called `calc_circle_area`, but it does not execute the function. The function is only executed when the function is called. So similarly, if I execute the following:

```
def func_a():
    return 'Function A'

def func_b():
    return 'Function B'
```

both functions are defined, but are not called. All that Python cares about is *whether the function is defined before it is called*. So:

```
def func_a():
    return 'Function A'

def func_b():
    return 'Function B'

print(func_a)
print(func_b)
```

gives exactly the same output as:

```
def func_b():
    return 'Function B'

def func_a():
    return 'Function A'

print(func_a)
print(func_b)
```

**The order of definition does not matter here.** So here, your code does the following:

- define `calc_circle_area`
- define `pizza_calories`
- call `pizza_calories`, and use the returned value in a print statement
- call `pizza_calories`, and use the returned value in a print statement

When `pizza_calories` is called, it uses the function `calc_circle_size` to produce `total_calories`. So, it calls `calc_circle_size`, and uses the return value to produce `total_calories`. If it's easier, you can think of the following equivalent code:

```
def pizza_calories(pizza_diameter):
    calories_per_square_inch = 16.7   

    ###

    # Here, I am using the same code as is used in calc_circle_area,
    # but with consistent variable names as is used in pizza_calories.

    pi_val = 3.14159265
    circle_radius = pizza_diameter / 2.0
    calc_circle_area_value = pi_val * circle_radius * circle_radius

    ###

    total_calories = calc_circle_area_value * calories_per_square_inch
    return total_calories

print('12 inch pizza has %.2f calories.'% pizza_calories(12.0))

print('14 inch pizza has %.2f calories.'% pizza_calories(14.0))
```

I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: wow, this actually made so much sense! I have been spending hours getting confused on one thing and then another which became like a huge ball of confusion. Thanks for saving my weekends! Much appreciated :)